# Error when connecting to sql-server using windows authentication mode

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, database-connection, sql-server-authentication

for a couple of days or weeks I am finding a solution to my problem on google but still, I don't get any solution so that's why am here to ask you to help me. Actually I am getting an error by connecting SQL server with java in Netbeans
here is the error

```
Cannot establish a connection to JDBC:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=newdb 
using com.Microsoft.SQL server.JDBC.SQLServerDriver 
(Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:7294b793-6d79-487a-be85-04cf286555a4)
```

I have done all settings in the SQL server which can cause to create this problem but there is no issue I really don't know why it's not connecting please guy help me with this issue I post below the screenshot of my SQL server configuration

1. [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcgVc.png)
2. [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKW5y.png)
3. [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRzAt.png)
4. [Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N5Y1.png)
5. [Screenshot 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ9dn.png)

Comment: the login of your user failed. have you verified your username and password?

Comment: which user in SQL server there is an option for verification?
am not using username and password in SQL server just using windows authentication

Comment: this one Login failed for user ''

Comment: yea this user login failed but i don't know why and what is the solution of this issue kindly guide me how can I resolve it and if there is any issue by authentication so can you please tell me how can i do this to solve this issue

Comment: the solution is to provide proper authentication

Comment: can you guide me how can i do proper authentication please bro

Comment: you mean to say user authentication i want